# Android: Dialog ,"window leaked" issue when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have two classes one adapter and one activity , i have a dailog which i am showing in the adapter. i am getting error when i tried to change the screen orientation..i tried overriding the below code in my activity. but nothing seems to work

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
          Log.d(TAG, "configuration changed : " +newConfig);

    }
```

below is my adapter code

```
public AddressPopUpAdapter(Activity activity, Activity parent,
            int resourceId, ArrayList<PopUpMenu> items, int renderer) {
        super(activity, resourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.parentActivity = parent;
        popupMenuUtils = new PopupMenuUtils();
        dialog = new Dialog(parentActivity);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        popUpMenu = items.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "location" + popUpMenu);
        if (popUpMenu == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "location" + popUpMenu);
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(renderer, null);

        }

        final LinearLayout popupmain = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.popupmain);

        popupmain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                performAction(v, activity);

            }
        });

        if (position % 2 == 0) {

            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);

        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void performAction(View v, Activity activity) {

        Context myContext = v.getContext();
        PopUpMenu popUpMenu = (PopUpMenu) v.getTag();
        String result = popUpMenu.getMenuName();
        if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.savecurrentlocation))) {
            getCurrentLocation();

        }

        else if (result != null
                && result.equalsIgnoreCase(myContext.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.distancebetween))) {
            AttractionService service = AttractionService
                    .getInstance(parentActivity.getApplicationContext());
            ArrayList<AttractionData> allMenuSearchList = service
                    .getAllAttractions(true, Constants.field, Constants.order);

            if (allMenuSearchList != null && !allMenuSearchList.isEmpty()) {

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pickdestination);
                ListView listPlace = (ListView) dialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.listPlace);
                PlaceAdapter placeAdapter = new PlaceAdapter(parentActivity,
                        allMenuSearchList, R.layout.pickcity, dialog,
                        R.string.pickstartingpoint, null);
                listPlace.setAdapter(placeAdapter);
giving error here----------->   dialog.show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, R.string.nonavigationtolink,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            this.activity.finish();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post also your manifest?

Comment: @Glenn  <activity android:name=".activity.AddressPopupActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"/>      this is the line for my activity in manifest

Comment: I had to `dismiss()` my dialog in the `onDestroy` callback, which gets called when changing device orientation. And then re-show the `dialog`, if necessary, in `onCreate` in the new orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is that you are not dismiss() your Dialog and finishing the activity so when orientation change it will get prior Dialog state.

So `try to dismiss() your dialog before you finish your activity.`

[See More Detail if any other cause :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: how can i dismiss the dailog in adapter, i think i have to dismiss in activity but the dailog is in adapter

Comment: you can dismiss dialog using that obj like my_dialog.dismiss()

Comment: tell me what is your dialog obj. no need of example.

Comment: do like  dialog.dismiss(); and then finish() your activity.

Comment: do i need to get refference of dailog in activity

Comment: yes you need to declare the dialog on activity level. 
Answer is correct trust him ;-)

Comment: i did this  dialog = new Dialog(activity); and this   
  @Override
   public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     dialog.dismiss();
     activity.finish();
  }
but getting null pointer exception

Comment: first see the dialog example and then try to implement in your main code so it's batter to you. other wise my answer in correct because same mistake i was done and solve resolve it.

Comment: you are doing wrong you cant direct pass activity you have to make custom dialog for more comfort level.

Comment: first see the dialog example and then try to implement in your main code so it's batter to you. other wise my answer in correct because same mistake i was done so.

Answer (score 2):

Per the above hints by chintan/Stephan; I made the AlertDialog reference global to the Activity and did dismiss in onDestroy():

```
if (ad!=null) {
 ad.dismiss();
 ad=null;
}
```

No more logged leak errors upon rotation.

I would not want to consider those configChanges parameters because they would mess things up if you already have specific layouts for landscape or such.

Answer (score -3):

a workaround for this issue is to add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

for your activity in the manifest.

Comment: I think you should add it like `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to work with version Honeycomb and above.

Comment: already that ..like this...<activity android:name=".activity.AddressPopupActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode‌​"/>